# Heroku created table but when I'll migrate, he says that doesn't created

Tags: django, deployment, heroku

I made syncdb (Python/Django application) in Heroku and he created table south_migrationhistory,

```
(venv-project)username@username:~/projectapp$ heroku run python manage.py syncdb
Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.5529
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table south_migrationhistory
```

(...)

```
Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > django.contrib.admin
 > south

Not synced (use migrations):
 - core
 - galeria
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

but when I'll migrate application he says that table wasn't created:

```
(venv-project)username@username:~/projectapp$ heroku run python manage.py migrate core
Running `python manage.py migrate core` attached to terminal... up, run.7542
```

(...monstruous log...)

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: south_migrationhistory
```

What can be? Thanks.

**EDIT**:
Solved, I put in settings_local gitignore and thereby recognized the database postgres heroku.

Comment: did you try to run only migrate, no core? `heroku run python manage.py migrate`

Comment: @catherine I found the error. How I use two settings, one for the server and another location, I forgot to put the "local" in gitignore. Thus, the settings_local was put on a server running and was invalidating the postgres on Heroku.

Comment: one for development and one for local?

Comment: @catherine Yes. In my "settings_local.py" I use sqlite3 and DEBUG=True, in "settings.py" I'm using dj-database-url, and others configs to database for Heroku

Comment: Ok in your local_settings.py, just put only database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**local_settings.py**

```
import os

SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'data.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

In your gitignore, add this:

```
project_name/local_settings.py
*.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 6):

**Tested on Django 1.9**

settings.py

```
in_heroku = False
if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
    in_heroku = True

import dj_database_url
if in_heroku:
    DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```

Then run:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
sudo apt-get intall postgresql libpq-dev
pip install dj-database-url psycopg2
pip freeze >requirements.txt
git add .
git commit -m 'msg'
git push heroku master
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

References:

- There is no more `syncdb`, just `migrate`: [What should I use instead of syncdb in Django 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683494/what-should-i-use-instead-of-syncdb-in-django-1-9)
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql