# "no such table" error on Heroku after django syncdb passed

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Django application to Heroku. The migrations are in my local Git. When I try:

```
git push heroku master
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

It applies the migrations and also promts me to create superuser, which I successfully do. Now the application is up and running, however when I try to log into the Django admin it's throwing:

```
OperationalError no such table: user_user
```

When I try

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations    
heroku run python manage.py migrate
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

It applies all migrations, but fails to create superuser throwing:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: user_user
```

Either way I can not have my database set up and migrated on Heroku.

My database settings are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

My user model is:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=settings.DEFAULT_USER_RATING)
```

Django version is 1.7.1.

How do I get my database tables created on Heroku?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say that running `migrate` applies the migrations. Well, do that instead of syncdb, which is deprecated anyway.

Comment: I have updated the question to become clearer. The issue is neither syncdb nor migrate help setting up the db on heroku. I still face "no such table: user_user" on trying to log into Django admin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku created table but when I'll migrate, he says that doesn't created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467389/heroku-created-table-but-when-ill-migrate-he-says-that-doesnt-created)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must not use sqlite3 on Heroku.

sqlite stores the database as a file on disk. But the filesystem in a Heroku dyno is not persistent, and is not shared between dynos. So, when you do `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, Heroku spins up a new dyno with a blank database, runs the migrations, then deletes the dyno and the database. The dyno that's running your site is unaffected, and never gets migrated.

You must use one of the Heroku database add-ons. There is a free tier for Postgres. You should use the dj-database-url library to set your database settings dynamically from the environment variables which Heroku sets.

Also, for the same reason, you must do `manage.py makemigrations` locally, commit the result to git, then push to Heroku.

Comment: I see now. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with Lumen/Laravel. Migrated and seeded locally, pushed to GitHub and then everything was working perfectly.

Comment: I had the same issue. I have added settings for postgreSql and added addon to heroku dyno. However, it still says no such table...

Comment: This is correct and as said sqlite should NOT be used on Heroku (or anywhere production). However, IF you're just playing with a test Django app AND IF your local data doesn't have anything sensitive you could commit/push your local sqlite DB file and this data will be shown. However, as Daniel said this is ephemeral and not shared across Dyno. It's a BAD IDEA but it may be fun if you're learning Django.

Answer (score 15):

You can use **postgresql**:

In `settings.py` add(at the end of file):

```
# ie if Heroku server
if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}
```

In `requirements.txt` add:

```
dj-database-url 
psycopg2
```

Now you can run: 
`heroku run python manage.py migrate`

Comment: psycopg2-binary works better here as psycopg2 may sometimes not compile without some dependencies

Answer (score 5):

`pip install django-heroku`

Add `import django_heroku` at top of file `settings.py`

Place `django_heroku.settings(locals())` at the very bottom of `settings.py`

It will automatically configure your db. You can learn more on their [website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration)

Comment: read a ton of other solutions but this was the only one that solved it. Looks like DATABASE_URL needs to be configured somehow to work with Heroku. Check the original documentation here: https://pypi.org/project/django-heroku/ dj_database_url seems to work as well: https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/

Answer (score 1):

What version of django you are using..?

If you are using django>=1.7 you need to run `migrate`

After adding models you need to do 
`python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate`

If your project already contain migrations you can directly run `python manage.py migrate` command.

If you miss any step mentioned above please do that.

Comment: Django version is 1.7.1. I have updated the question text - migrate applies the migrations, however createsuperuser fails after that.