# heroku no such table: auth_user error when trying to run create superuser

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to create my django app w/ Heroku however I'm stuck on this error. I have seen some information on heroku not being able to use sqllite so I've been trying to update to postgres but not sure why that's not reflected here.

sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user

```
heroku run python3 manage.py createsuperuser

 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.41.0 to 7.60.1.
Running python3 manage.py createsuperuser on ⬢ generic-heroku-app... up, run.5883 (Free)
On development database

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

*DB from settings.py*

```
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '**',
        'USER': '**',
        'PASSWORD': '**',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Edit: this thread shows some solid info but I still can't seem to make it work with this info. Not sure where I'm going wrong.. ["no such table" error on Heroku after django syncdb passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766780/no-such-table-error-on-heroku-after-django-syncdb-passed)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to run your migrations `python manage.py migrate `

Comment: `python3 manage.py migrate
On development database
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.`

Comment: this is what I get when i run that ^^. I've migrated everything and pushed to git but keep running into this.

Comment: The migrations haven't been applied to whatever database you are running the `createsuperuser` command against, you can see in the output `You have 18 unapplied migration(s) `

Comment: Yupp, how can I apply those correctly tho?

Comment: However or wherever you ran that `createsuperuser` command, you need to run migrations in the same environment. I assume the command would be `heroku run python3 manage.py migrate`

Comment: just tried that and still getting the same error..

Comment: When I run `python3 manage.py createsuperuser ` locally it runs fine. I'm also able to stand up the app on localhost without any problems. It's just this stage...

Answer (score 1):

If your project is connected with github deploy, then in your project, in Procfile, add:

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi
```

Comment: This is currently what I have: `web: gunicorn django_local_library.wsgi --log-file -
release: python manage.py migrate`. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: What is your version of django? Why aren't you using 'django.db.backends.postgresql' instead of 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'?

Comment: Django version == 3.2.13. I'm new to Django so following tutorials of what other people are doing online. Will that solve this error? @Lucas

Comment: Because it is a study, I suggest you use another tutorial. I believe it will be more beneficial for you.

Comment: that's not helpful... There's no tutorial for why this error is occurring for a locally functional django application. You should try to add helpful information.

Comment: @Tai can you put your code into an github reporitory and share the link with us?

Comment: https://github.com/tfurbs/django_local_library it's right here!